# Azure Application Insights view log chart. Data included in the log message

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

Using Azure Application Insights to view the log done by Serilog. I wonder why the parameter is a part of the event string. This causes the graph to use a different color for each time the event is logged.

[image]

The logging is done like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("job is running {Time}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

I expected the {Time} "interpolation" to cause the logger to log this string instead: `job is running {Time}`

Is it normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the message property is the fully rendered string and the custom dimensions property of the `trace` record contains the template as shown in this example:

[image]

So if the Application Insights view is configured / changed to use the `customDimension.OriginalFormat` instead of `message` your problem is solved.

Now it depends a bit on the lib that processes the log, in your case it might be called different like `MessageTemplate` instead of `OriginalFormat`.

Comment: Here it is called MessageTemplate instead of OriginalFormat.